# MySQL server And VB 2008 security

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, security

Hello stackoverflower!
Okay i am planning of crating a WindowsFormApplication in VisualBasics that interact with an online database i know how to connect  visual basics to MySQL server.
In the programme i have to add the database credentiels Username + password.
Now the question is this way of connecting directly to mysql secure?
Is their a way hacker could see the source code of VB 2008?
Is their a way of tracking the username and password of the database on the local network?
If the answer is yes vulnerable how to secure it?   Please tell me so i can start develloping this programm

Comment: The source code is yours, how could you not see it?

Comment: @Dona I can see it is their any methods or software that decompile the extendible application to readable source code then it will be a major security risk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Stackoverflowwer,
Sorry for bothering and after days and days of researching i have found that the best way of communicating with an online databse is with PHP and pages request

Thanks everyone for your effort,

Regards,

:D

Answer (score 1):

There are several [decompilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) out there. And if you do not [obfuscate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29) your code, which is limited protection, they can see all your source code after decompilation.

Yes people can track your user names and passwords once sent over the network. To protect it, your app sends an encrypted version of what your username and password are, then decrypt it inside the app to check if the user typed in the right stuff.

Comment: obfuscate is never enough to protect my application from decompilers and then search for the connection string in it and see the UID and pass example any programm how much it was encrypted need this part `Conn.connectionstring = "...Stuffs...UID="root"pass="Pa$$w0rd"....` so the hacker search for connection string and find the UID and pass this hack the hole database.Want I want is a way of communication with an online MySQL server in another way than this traditional way please advice + thanks you for answering my question but one left :D